# Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

While logging into MySQL using `'root'@10.0.1.15'`

I tried to grant a user `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE` but got this error from MySQL

```
Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'root'@'10.%' to database 'abc'
```

This is the query that I used to grant

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON abc.* TO 'myUser'@'10.%';
```

This makes no since because when I execute  SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'10.%' Here is what I get

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'jklasdfksfkashdfksdfhsdlkfasdfjklasdfsjk'
```

I tried to do grant all privileges all over again but still getting the same error.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

What I could be doing wrong here? why aren't the user 'root'@'10.0.1.15' able to GRANT other users privileges?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your user needs the `GRANT OPTION`.

Here's how to change your existing grant to fix that:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* 
TO 'root'@'10.%' 
IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'jklasdfksfkashdfksdfhsdlkfasdfjklasdfsjk' 
WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: a lot of ppl seem to miss the `with grant option`. I think it has to do with localhost root having that option by default. +1

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* 
TO 'root'@'10.%' 
WITH GRANT OPTION` but it is still not working

Comment: It worked after I started a new session to the server. Thank you so much