# using python to create tables on mysql, access denied

Tags: python, mysql

Hey I'm trying to create table on MySQL using Python, the user `s0566293` has all the grants on the table but i still get `1044 (42000) access denied`, any suggestions?.

Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="141.45.91.40",
    user="s0566293",
    passwd="6172I9wf",
    database="dbproject"
)
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
#Here creating database table as student'
db_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE fil (filName INT, Genre VARCHAR(255))")
#Get database table'
db_cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
for table in db_cursor:
    print(table)
```

Comment: did you do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after grant option to the user?

Comment: Yes i did, but i couldnt show the password as i wrote Show user, host from thedb the filed of the password didnt apper ig thats why it says access denied.

Comment: I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123685/error-code-1044-access-denied-for-user). 1044 is not a password problem, it's about privileges.